# apache web server doesnt read html in htdocs

Tags: html, apache, webserver

I'm using linux mint and I'm install Apache web server. When I'm testing him in web browser I can see

```
It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.
```

But if I'm trying to added one more html docs in the `htdocs` directory. I;m restart the server, but I have an 404 error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /test.html was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Now I'm open index.html which located in `htdocs` just after installation the server. It contains the following:

```
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

Now I'm trying to change it, but there is no effect when I'm trying to view it in browser `http://localhost/index.html`.

Question: What is a possible reason of this trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DocumentRoot` for apache2 on Linux Mint is `/var/www/`.

To change the default message,  edit `/var/www/index.html`.

Put new files in `/var/www/`

You don't need to restart apache after updating or adding files, changes are seen immediately.